# Cauchy-Riemann conditions satisfying the Laplacian

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How does one convert the Cauchy-Riemann conditions
 into the form:

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2} = 0, \qquad \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2v}{\partial y^2} = 0$$

from

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}, \qquad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

to show that a differentiable complex function has real and imaginary parts that separately satisfy the Laplace equation?
The book that I'm working with says that by "differentiating first with respect to x and then with respect to y, one easily obtains (equation 2)", but my calc3 is weak and I fail to see it.

Comment: I think this could be considered a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848464/function-ux-y-in-c2-that-admits-harmonic-conjugate/1132987#1132987

Comment: All analytic functions are harmonic. Just differentiate those two C.R. Equations and add them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$, then $u_{xx} = v_{yx}$ and $u_{yy} = -v_{xy}$. Hence $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = v_{yx} - v_{xy} = 0$. Since $v_x = -u_y$, $v_{xx} = -u_{yx}$;  since $v_y = u_x$, $v_{yy} = u_{xy}$. Therefore $v_{xx} + v_{yy} = -u_{yx} + u_{xy} = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

We will use the Schwarz theorem for the second derivatives, which states that 
$$
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}
$$
for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$. The Cauchy-Riemann equations are defined as
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}, ~~~~~(1) \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}. ~~~~~(2)
$$
Differentiating $(1)$ with respect to $x$ and $(2)$ with respect to $y$ gives us
$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial^2x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y\partial x},~\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x\partial y}.
$$
Applying the Schwarz theorem to interchange the derivatives $\partial x\partial y$ and $\partial y\partial x$, we get
$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=-\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}\Rightarrow \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=0.
$$
Differentiating $(1)$ with respect to $y$ and $(2)$ with respect to $x$: 
$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial y^2},~\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y\partial x}=-\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial x^2}.
$$
Applying the Schwarz theorem to interchange the derivatives $\partial x\partial y$ and $\partial y\partial x$, we conclude 
$$
\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial y^2}=-\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial x^2}\Rightarrow \frac{\partial^2v}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial y^2}=0.~_{\square}
$$

Comment: I haven't seen the Schwarz theorem before. Is there any counter example to this ?

Comment: No. It is a known theorem for a function $f\in C^2$.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives